# Why can't I connect to unsecure open wireless networks?

Tags: 10.04, wireless, networking

I have an open, unsecured router which I can connect to without any issues while in Windows.

When I am in Ubuntu, if I click on my *wireless manager* to see all the networks, then it shows all the secured networks around me but does not show my unsecured one.

I looked all over the place for a setting that could maybe filter out open networks and not show them. But I did not find anything. I do not know what is going on.

I often use the networks at Starbucks and hotels because I travel a lot. This is going to be a big problem for me. Can someone please point me in some direction?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with all updates applied and installed. I'm also using a Hawkings Wireless USB card. It uses the rt73 drivers that come installed default.

Comment: You might need to change the broadcasting channel, most routers have a setting for that. To figure out what channel to pick, look at the output of `nm-tool`, and of `sudo iwlist wlan0 channel`.

Comment: I've tried to change the channel already I didn't think to mention that. Still didn't help.

Comment: You are *not* hiding the SSID of that router/WAP, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting from the terminal and setting your IP manually

`iwconfig [interface] mode managed key open`
`iwconfig [interface] essid [ESSID]`

Set your IP Address `ifconfig [interface] [IP address] netmask [subnetmask]`

Add ip of router as default gateway `route add default gw [IP of default gateway]`

Configure dns 
`echo nameserver [IP address of DNS server]  >>  /etc/resolve.conf`